# Installing Agda on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: haskell, emacs, osx-mavericks, agda

I am having trouble installing agda on my mac. I am taking my instructions from here:

http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.MacOSX

I was able to get the Haskell platform installed and when I run cabal update it works . When I run:

```
cabal install agda
```

it originally installed and now it offers me the option to reinstall, so I believe that is correct. The problem arises when i run the last command,

```
$ agda-mode setup
```

It outputs

```
-bash: agda-mode: command not found
```

I have also tried installing on my virtual box because the windows install seems a lot easier, but when I attempt to run the .msi files I get an error that "this file is not compatible with your processor". I allowed the virtual windows to use up to 8 processors (the max) so that doesn't seem like its going to be an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the default Cabal binary installation directory in your PATH? I think it's either `~/.cabal/bin` or `~/Library/Haskell/bin`.

Comment: Yes-- I added export PATH=“$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin:$PATH” to my .profile

Comment: Have you searched for the executable to make sure it is in your PATH? I've only ever seen `~/.cabal/bin`, so make sure it isn't residing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem it was fixed after adding ~/.cabal/bin to the PATH.

Comment: Do you mean adding that exact line to the file with 'sudo nano /etc/paths' ? Because I added that line there and it still doesn't work.